# Is it a scam if they want my email, name on bank account, and bank name?

Tags: scams

A stranger told me that he will give me an allowance of $ weekly. I know the saying "If it sounds too good to be true, then it is".

He told me that he would  email me his check and I would be able to deposit it via mobile banking. The only information he needs is my email, name on bank account, and bank name.

Is this too much information? Do you think this is a scam? I would definitely know if it was a scam if he asked for my log in but that is not what he wants.

Thank you for your time and answers!

Comment: So why is a complete stranger going to give you a weekly allowance?

Comment: Not a complete stranger but stranger enough for there to be trust issues

Comment: So why would a stranger give you a weekly allowance? Have you done anything in return? If not it is a scam in the making! Be smart and stop thinking with your greed!!!

Answer (score 12):

It is a scam. If you look in the "Related" column on the right side of the page you'll *many* similar questions. In some cases the scammer will ask for the login info, but in other cases they won't. The risks of giving someone your bank login and password are obvious. Banks almost always require that you keep your password a secret as part of their terms of service. This means that the bank is not going to be sympathetic if you tell them you got robbed by someone you gave your password to.

Even if they don't ask for a password, it's still a scam. The scam works by taking advantage of the fact that different parts of the banking system operate at different speeds. The scammer sends you a forged or stolen check, and you deposit it in your account. Check processing is very slow! *It may take over a month for the bank to determine that the check was bogus.* In the meantime the bank will generally make at least some portion of the funds available to you after a few days. You are, after all, a valued, honest, customer.

The scammer will then ask for a portion of the money back, sometimes a surprisingly small portion. They will have you transfer the money to them using cash, a gift card, a bank wire, Bitcoin, or Western Union. The point being that unlike a bad check, the transfer to them will be quick and irreversible. When the bank finally figures out that the original deposit was a fraud, the bank will hold **you** responsible for the **full** amount of the original deposit including whatever you've already spent yourself, and the portion you transferred back to the scammer.

But wait, you say! What if I never send the scammer the money they ask for? Remember, the whole point of this scam is that the check is bogus! The scammer is not out any money if you don't send them their cut. They just move on to their next victim, and you still have to pay the bank back for any of the money you spend from the bad check.

The number of people in the world who will contact strangers or near-strangers to give away cash is essentially zero. Unfortunately, there are **millions** of people in the world who willing to prey on the greedy, the gullible, and the desparate.

Comment: Thank you for your time and I appreciate the explanation in your response!

Answer (score 4):

So far, with that info, he can't steal your money - but the thick end will come. There are no strangers that give you checks, life is not a Disney fairy tale.

He might give you a larger check after some weeks, and ask you to cash out a piece of it and give him, or such. Then he disappears, and some days later the bank calls you that the check was fake - and you are out of the cash you gave him.

Answer (score -5):

Apologies for the the age of the question.

OK, so they are not asking for an account number.  It is normal to ask for an account number and account name.  Providing the email address you supply is not known to the Bank this could be legit. A lot of invoices are paid this way by direct deposit. They can set up a periodic payment. I am surprised they can do this without an account number, as you may have a number of accounts, and you may not have a unique name.

You have said they are known to you but not well. This could well be legit.

Comment: Going further, the absence of a request for an account number strongly suggests the payments are "court mandated", as the Bank is obliged to comply with a court order as far account numbers go. (The opposite of a garnishee order)  You should be across this, you likely have certain rights you may wish to exercise.